# Which book is the maxim 大道無門 from?

Tags: quote-source, japanese-language, chinese-language

From which book is the maxim

> 大道無門

[image: Go player Fan]

Zen kōan だいどうむもん "Daidō mumon"
"to achieve great understanding there is no single but thousands of ways".

Comment: What language is this? You've tagged your question with both Japanese and Chinese, but which is it?

Comment: I don't know which, so I tagged both.

Comment: Strangely enough, it seems to be a mixture: according to Google Translate, 大道無門 is Chinese while だいどうむもん and 藤沢秀行 are Japanese. Also, what's the image?

Comment: From a fan where I got the quote. And 藤沢秀行 is a name Fujisawa Hideyuki (from the fan too).

Comment: @Randal'Thor Google translate has a bad habit of defaulting to Chinese for text purely in Kanji (unless the text has some Kokuji characters).

Comment: @Randal'Thor The Chinese writing system was imported into Japan in several waves of manuscripts, mostly Buddhist scripts, from China. Wumen Huikai lived in China and were probably also exported to Japan, hence the Japanese name. I assume he wrote in Chinese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“大道無門” is the first line of a verse:

> 大道無門
>   千差有路
>   透得此關
>   乾坤獨步

This is from the introduction to [無門關](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gateless_Barrier), usually translated as *The Gateless Barrier* or *The Gateless Gate*, a collection of kōans by Zen master [Wúmén Huìkāi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wumen_Huikai) (無門慧開), published in 1228. (He is perhaps better known in the West under the Japanese version of his name, Mumon Ekai.) In Robert Aitken’s translation:

> The Great Way has no gate;
>   there are a thousand different paths;
>   once you pass through this barrier,
>   you walk the universe alone.

“大道無門” contains a pun: the author’s name Wúmén is written with the same characters (無門) as “no gate” so the line can be understood as “Wúmén’s Great Way” as well as “the great way has no gate”.

“だいどうむもん” (daidō mumon) is the Japanese pronunication of “大道無門” (dàdào wú mén).

[Hideyuki Fujisawa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hideyuki_Fujisawa) (藤沢秀行) was a professional Go player also known for his calligraphy: presumably the writing on the fan is his work.

Comment: In Chinese, I would expect “Wúmén’s Great Way” to be rendered as 無門(的)大道, not “大道無門” (which just means "great way, no gate"; the verb is implied). Does the other word order work in Japanese?